# Is this file size adequate for jpeg images?

Tags: photoshop, jpeg, file-size

While my photos usually are ~ 150kb average, I find some to double that size under the same settings. Specially Black & White photos.

Is this size normal, because of the amount of different tones or am I missing something?

Settings:
JPEG, RGB, 8 Bits, width 960px
Saved with Photoshop at quality level 8

Example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm7nesnlq945tt6/_MG_8281_bw.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Looks normal to me, you are getting a bit of pixelation but at PS Level 8 you should be fine. 960px isn't huge but for web viewing might be exactly what you want. It certainly is too small for printing though if you intend to do that.

Comment: Thank you, yes, the intention is to post them in my website, that's why I'm worried about file size.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's normal for JPEG file sizes to vary quite a bit.

The file size reflects how much information there is in the image. In your image you have a lot of structure in the grass, concrete and leaves, which means that there is more information in the image.

Black and white photos will generally give larger file sizes, at least when saved as RGB rather than grayscale. Reducing unneeded color information is a big part of the JPEG compression, and in a black and white image there is no color information to reduce. The grayscale expressed as RGB means that the image has quite high contrast compared to a color image, so it has more information.